# Yii2 routing problems,don't recognise parameters

Tags: web, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

Every time a make request to http://localhost/users?username="john.doe", I get **404 error**.

The following code is **Controller** code to control routes.

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => [ 'users'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['users'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }
```

**Controller** action code.

```
public function actionUsers($username)
{
        
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return Users::find()->where('username', $username)->one();
        }
}
```

***PS:*** I'm make ajax request.

Comment: The behaviors definition you've posted doesn't control routing. AccessControl only checks if current user can access current action.
Routing is controled by UrlManager setting in your config file. It's in `web.php` for basic app template.
Also, the 404 code doesn't mean the parameter wasn't recognised. If parameter wasn't recognised you would get 400 Bad Request error. The 404 in this case probably means the framework couldn't find what controller/action should be used for this request.

Comment: which controller you are using ??

Comment: Also, you `where()` call looks incorrect, see https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you action `actionUsers` is inside a controller name `MyuserController` then your link should be

```
 http://localhost/myuser/users?username="john.doe"
```

Your link must contain also the name of the controller (not only the name of the action)